# How can I add navigation arrows on the "Simplest jQuery Slideshow"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slideshow

I am using the "Simplest jQuery Slideshow" from snook.ca (http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow) and I love it. I quote the code here:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){
  $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
    .next('img').fadeIn()
    .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
  3000);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fadein { position:relative; width:500px; height:332px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fadein">
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
</div>
```

I would like to add to arrows to go to the next and the last images manually on click. Since I haven't found a solution yet anywhere, and I have no idea on Jquery I am asking this question here...

Realy thanks to you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    $('.nextButton').on('click', function(){
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
           .next('img').fadeIn()
           .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    });
    $('.previousButton').on('click', function () {
        $('.fadein :last-child').fadeIn()
            .insertBefore($('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut());
    });
});
```

It's different going backwards, because the other script is taking advantage of `appendTo` and the current `img` being at index 0. You'll have to provide the buttons, but it's pretty simple. You can try it out on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xu2W/1/).

Comment: Hi @ShadowCat7, Thank you very much for your help! What you said works perfectly. I wanted to show the link cursor when being over the arrow, and i needed to do it with <a href="javascript:void(0)">, if not it did'nt worked.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You can do that in css with
`.nextButton, .previousButton { cursor: pointer }`